# What causes "Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver..." at runtime in my servlet?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jakarta-ee, servlets, jdbc

I want to be able to click on an HTML button and have it call a method inside of Java. Is there more than one way to accomplish this task.

I also would like to see where the errors are coming from on this example. It will not compile.

Java Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/myservlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        if (request.getParameter("button1") != null) {
            myClass.function1();
        } else if (request.getParameter("button2") != null) {
            myClass.function2();
        } else if (request.getParameter("button3") != null) {
            myClass.function3();
        } 
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some-result.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}

class MyClass {
    void function1() {
        System.out.println("Button 1");
    }

    void function2() {
        System.out.println("Button 2");
    }

    void function3() {
        System.out.println("Button 3");
    }
}
```

html code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Button</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Button 1" />
    <input type="submit" name="button2" value="Button 2" />
    <input type="submit" name="button3" value="Button 3" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
May 30, 2014 1:16:54 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection <init>
SEVERE: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.<init>(SQLServerConnection.java:304)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1011)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at testpak.DbTest.testQuery(DbTest.java:19)
    at testpak.DbTest.main(DbTest.java:30)
```

[image]

[image]

That sqljdbc4jar. is in my Referenced Library. Is there another place that it needs to be?

Comment: First of all, it *is* compiling. You have a runtime error. And the error is quite clear and tells you what you need to do: `Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.`

Comment: FYI, when you have a question about an error, please read the stacktrace and include the code the error is being thrown from (`testpak.DbTest.testQuery()`)

Comment: sqljdbc4.jar is included in my referenced Library. But in this example I am not really using SQL so to speak, but rather just trying to call some methods.

Comment: You could always tell Eclipse to run it under JDK6 to make sure that's the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to your own screenshot you are referencing both `sqljdbc.jar` and `sqljdbc4.jar`. You should only reference one (in this case: `sqljdbc4.jar`).

These jar files contain the same driver classes (although the exact implementation might be different). The classloader loads the classes from the first jar on the classpath, and ignores those in the second as it has already loaded a class with the same name.